# How do I write CSS selectors with CSS Counters to apply formatting to a specific element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a Table of Contents in HTML/CSS using CSS Counters, and nested OLs, which works great. Now, I want to set a class "toc" on the top level OL (because there are more OLs on the page than just the table of contents).

How do I adjust the CSS selectors so that the counter styles only apply to `<ol class="toc">`?

If you remove, the class="toc" from the first OL, you'll see the item numbers are nested as you'd expect...when you add the toc class back, it all goes to pot. How do I fix the css selectors so that the nested item numbers work as expected?

```
<style>
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                /* Creates a new instance of the
                                            section counter with each ol
                                            element */
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;            /* Increments only this instance
                                            of the section counter */
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";   /* Adds the value of all instances
                                            of the section counter separated
                                            by a ".". */
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>​


<ol class="toc">

    <li>item
    <ol>
        <li>item
        <li>item
            <ol>
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>item
    </ol>
</li>  
<li>item
    <ol>
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
    </ol>

</li> 
<li>item
    <ol>
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
        <li>item
    </ol>

</li> 
<li>item
    <ol>
        <li>item
            <ol>
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item
            </ol>
        </li>

        <li>item
            <ol>
                <li>item
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item
                <li>item</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>item
            <ol>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ol>
    </ol>
</li> 
</ol>​
```

Comment: I know that I could wrap the whole thing in a div, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without additional elements?

Comment: What *is* "right set of OLs"?  Please provide an example of the desired result.

Comment: Tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: so .toc just breaks it? i don't see .toc declared in the styles

Comment: Can you post perhaps a screenshot of the output you're looking for? Your "clarification" isn't very clear to be quite frank...

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
ol { color:black; }

ol.parentol { color:red; }

ol.childol { color:green; }

 /* nested ols with class of 'childol' 
  will not inherit the red font color */
</style>
<ol>
  <li>zzzzz</li>
  <li>
    <ol class="parentol">
      <li>aaaa</li>
      <li>
       <ol class="childol">
         <li>bbb</li>
       </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did you try this? I don't think this works with the nested CSS counters.

Comment: yes, css flows down. Having a the classes allows you to overide . updated my answer

Comment: Where do I see CSS counters in this answer?

Comment: because (it looks) that counters are irrelevant to the question ( op would need to define "goes to pot " ect and explain what is trying to be achieved ). no suck eggs intended